# [MKAnnotation]warning: '-setTitle:' not found in protocol(s)

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

i have a subclass named `MyAnnotation` to manage the annotation protocol, my problem is when i build the application, it gives me this warning :

```
'-setTitle:' not found in protocol(s)
```

the compiler point me to this line which causes the warning :

```
annView.annotation.title = @"You are here";
```

where `annView` is a `MKPinAnnotationView` :

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentLoc"];
```

can you please help me to fix that warning ? thx in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `annotation` property of `MKPinAnnotationView` (which is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`) is of type `id<MKAnnotation>` which doesn't define a `-setTitle:` method.

However, if your class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol defines a `-setTitle:` method for itself (using an `@property` declaration, for example), ***then*** you can set the title as follows:

```
MyAnnotationClass *myAnnot = (MyAnnotationClass *)annView.annotation;
myAnnot.title = @"You are here";
```

But you should probably set the annotation's title when you create it and before calling `addAnnotation` instead of setting it in `viewForAnnotation`.

Also, naming your class `MkAnnotation` is probably not a good idea.  It can easily be confused with the `MKAnnotation` protocol.  Use something like `MalekAnnotation` instead.

Comment: Hi, in my class that implement the annotation protocol, should i do this :  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * title; ?? and in the .m should i write the setter for that property : -(void)setTitle:(NSString *)newTitle  ?? if yes, how can i invoc that property in my extern class?? 'cause your code gives me errors:( thx

Comment: In the .h do @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; and in the .m just do @synthesize (and release in dealloc).